# Wordpress custom titles

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add custom titles to my wordpress theme and I am having a bit of trouble.

I know I can use AIOSeo but it adds so many functions that I wont use, so I am trying to make this on my own.

I have added a few inputs in my theme settings page (one for home, one for categories and so on) and I would like to be able to store my title structure in those fields.

I have managed the storing part, but I cant make the proper output.

For instance, if for the index title I store "get_bloginfo('name')", when I echo it, it says "get_bloginfo('name')" and not "My blog name"

How can I achieve that?

BTW, I am trying this

```
if ( is_page() ) {
echo $pagetitle;
```

Best regards!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you actually storing "get_bloginfo('name')" as a string then trying to echo it? Either way get_bloginfo('name') will display your blog name wherever it is echo'd.

Comment: can you show us the code where you are declaring your `$pagetitle` and `$indextitle` variables?

Comment: @BenRacicot: Yes, I am storing "get_bloginfo('name')" in the database but when I echo it, it doesnt echo the blogs name.

Comment: @JP Lew: I declare them here
 $options = get_option('games_theme_settings');
 $pagetitle = $options['pagetitle'];

Comment: and what happens when you `echo $pagetitle`? How are you storing your index title (the one assigned to `get_bloginfo()`? And another thing, your `if` statement is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: When I echo $pagetitle it prints what is stored in the database. For instance, I stored "get_bloginfo('name')" and it echoes "get_bloginfo('name')" and not my site name's. I know its missing a bracket, its just a part of the full code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the filter [`wp_title`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/general-template.php#L644) and manipulate the output. Check the whole function to see how WordPress deals with this.

Here's an example:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'title_so_18414286', 10, 3 );

function title_so_18414286( $title, $sep, $seplocation )
{
    if ( is_category() || is_tag() ) {
        $title = 'Title for Category';
    }
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $title = 'Page not found';
    }
    return $title
}
```

Comment: This quite didn't exactly answered my question but gave me the idea on how to approach my problem on a different and much better way. Thanks!